# Collectionview cell height from label height swift

Tags: swift, autolayout, collectionview

I'm trying to create a collection view that can be resized automatically from label height. I have two different cell, one of them with photo another without photo and both in xib files.

I've tried different ways to make this height dynamic but no solution ((.

```
var CollectionViewCellNib = UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(CollectionViewCellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
var CollectionViewCellWithPhotoNib = UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCellWithPhoto", bundle: nil)
collectionView.registerNib(CollectionViewCellWithPhotoNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let pikirler = self.pikirler[indexPath.row]
        let targetWidth: CGFloat = (self.collectionView.bounds.width - 2 * kHorizontalInsets)

        if indexPath.row == 2 {
            var cell = self.offscreenCells[CollectionViewKeyWords.collectionViewOnlyTextCell] as? CollectionViewCell
            if cell == nil {
                cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CollectionViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CollectionViewCell

                self.offscreenCells[CollectionViewKeyWords.collectionViewOnlyTextCell] = cell
            }
            cell!.configCell("sometext", content: "sometext")
            cell!.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, cell!.bounds.height)
            cell!.contentView.bounds = cell!.bounds
            cell!.setNeedsLayout()
            cell!.layoutIfNeeded()
            var size = cell!.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
            size.width = targetWidth

            return size
        }else{
            var cell = self.offscreenCells[CollectionViewKeyWords.collectioViewWithPhotoCell] as? CollectionViewCellWithPhoto
            if cell == nil {
                cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CollectionViewCellWithPhoto", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? CollectionViewCellWithPhoto

                self.offscreenCells[CollectionViewKeyWords.collectioViewWithPhotoCell] = cell
            }
            cell!.configCell("Some text", content: "sometext")
            cell!.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetWidth, cell!.bounds.height)
            cell!.contentView.bounds = cell!.bounds
            cell!.setNeedsLayout()
            cell!.layoutIfNeeded()

            var size = cell!.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
            size.width = targetWidth

            return size

        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout? You can subclass `UICollectionViewCell`, and override `intrinsicContentSize` - that might do the trick.

Comment: Also, here's a snippet that I use when I have UITextViews that need sizing dynamically: http://pastebin.com/LixHPG1U